# RSA algorithm -- cannot verify d

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, rsa

So I'm testing my RSA algorithm and I think I'm doing it wrong.

If I understand correctly, to produce d -- I need to find d*e or 1 mod (p-1)(q-1) (since they're supposed to be congruent).

Something like this

```
   d = e.modInverse(p_1.multiply(q_1))
```

Unfortunately, I don't get how 1 mod any number is going to be anything other than 1.

For example: p = 17, q = 11, e = 7, d = 23

23*7 = 161, but 1 mod (17-1)(11-1) = 1 not 161.

What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find `d` such that

```
d*e = 1 mod ((p-1)(q-1)),
```

which is the same as saying

```
d = e^(-1) mod ((p-1)(q-1)).
```

Take a more careful look at how the RSA algorithm works. So basically you have to find the multiplicative inverse of `e` modulo `(p-1)(q-1)`.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much!  7^-1 mod (17-1)(11-1) is indeed 23 (i.e. d)!